# How to determine the reason for Windows spontaneous shutdown?

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, event-viewer

**Update 2**: Tracking the reasons for a few shutdowns in the past couple of weeks, using the Event Viewer without filtering events, to get to the approximate time of shutdown, it seems like the last few shutdowns were caused by system overheating, and not by some malicious script or process.

I will continue to monitor that and update this question if new findings are observed.

---

**Update 1**: I used Sysinteranls Autoruns utility as suggested by @Mark, and listed all the (non-Microsoft) startup objects, to look for a script that supposedly calls `Shutdown`. After exporting and cleaning the list of the known binary file types (`.exe`, `.sys`, `.dll`) I saw two proprietary binary files belonging to a specific application which I installed some time ago. The computer was problematic long before I installed that app, so I do not think those are related to the problem, but I uninstalled it anyway. Other than the binaries and a few `File not found` entries, there are no other entries in the list.

Is there a way to log *what* application called the `shutdown.exe` utility?

---

**Original question:** My Dell E7450 Win10 laptop regularly shuts itself down spontaneously. Looking online, I found a [couple of resources](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/how-can-you-find-the-cause-of-unexpected-shutdown/54cf6947-0cc2-4719-ab47-9f9cb989de8f) pointing to the Event Viewer application.

Following the instructions, I am able to see the list of shutdown events (codes 1074, 6006, 6008). It seems like no 6006 and 6008 events are recorded. Of the multiple 1074 events, I see a few that are related to the software updates, but many that are related to the spontaneous shutdowns.

Examining the event(s), they all look like the following. The reason code is `0x800000ff` and no reason nor comment are provided.

I can normally immediately turn the computer on again, and log into Windows.

Upon these shutdowns, the work is not properly saved, if not by the auto-save features of the various running apps (if they have ones). With Chrome, I sometimes get the "Restore previous session" popup, and sometimes have to go through the History menu to reopen the previous Chrome windows.

How can I determine the reason for those shutdowns?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check Scheduled Tasks.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Why would a script induce so many destructive shutdowns? How do you find that script?

Comment: Shutdown exe is a program that shuts down the computer. So someone is either typing it or a script or program is executing it. Proper programs do not call user commands so ask your friends. See my comments here https://superuser.com/questions/1526680/why-does-explorer-seem-to-deadlock#comment2314511_1526680. Use Autoruns Everything tab and hide Microsoft Entries. One of them should be your friend's file.

Comment: ... thanks for the pointers, but I am not sure what you are implying with "my (ex-)friend", esp. w/ that legal note??? I don't have friends in our organization's IT department nor at Dell...

Comment: Also, I noticed those events tend to happen more when on my home network (normally on WiFi and VPN) and less when docked at the office (normally wired, but they do happen there as well).

Comment: You need to find what is executing `shutdown` Windows never executes it itself. Programs ask Windows directly to shutdown via the API, and programs that do that are rare. Your friend has played a joke or you are infected with a real virus or IT have stuffed up (most likely some complicated way they came up with installing updates). Use Autoruns to find it.

Comment: @Mark - please see the update to the Q.

Comment: Whoever voted to close this question on the basis of "Need more focus" - would you be kind enough and suggest how to add more focus to this question, when I already provided all the information I had at the time???

Comment: As an admin rename `c:\windows\system32\shutdown.exe` (to Shutdown1 perhaps). If an elevated command prompt type `takeown /f shutdown.exe /a` then `cacls shutdown.exe /g administrators:F` then `ren shutdown.exe shutdown1.exe`. If the program doesn't out itself when it can't find `shutdown.exe` the next step is to put our own one in it's place.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give the removal of the `.ax` files a chance for a while and then try this procedure. I'll report back then.

Answer (score 0):

Tracking the reasons for a few shutdowns in the past couple of weeks, using the Event Viewer without filtering events, to get to the approximate time of shutdown, it seems like the last few shutdowns were caused by system overheating, and not by some malicious script or process.

I will continue to monitor that and update this question if new findings are observed.

Comment: any insights on the matter? I recently experience spontaneous shutdowns of my Dell E7450 as well. Any chance this is related to your Chrome browser, or to Google Update Helper? (check "Reliability Monitor" -- any warnings there from these apps?)

Comment: @Yaniv - no new insights. The only specific reason I could identify is the heating. However, I cannot attribute all of the shutdowns to heating with confidence. I haven't followed the issue for a while. I just live with it, expecting occasional spontaneous shutdowns with defensive usage (like, frequent workspace saves, etc.).

Comment: I started writing a comment here, but it's too long and detailed, so I'll write it as an answer here... :/

Comment: See my answer here. I have experienced symptoms similar to your case, and after 10 days with no shutdowns it is ~safe to say that I have resolved it..? (still crossing my fingers that they are really gone). My guess is that the Intel Thermal Framework Driver, possibly along with its interactions with other software updates, was to blame.

Answer (score 0):

The **symptoms** I witnessed in my Dell E7450, Windows 10:

- Spontaneous shutdowns.
- In the "Reliability Monitor" (easier UI compared to "Event Viewer") I saw not only the shutdowns, but many warnings by Google Updater. I blamed Chrome for that.
- The battery icon (at the taskbar) sometimes showed an icon of a battery crossed out, as if the battery is not recognized. I almost bought a new battery just because of that.

The **changes** I made about 5 days ago, that *seem* to have stopped the all symptoms (for now... crossing my fingers):

1. Uninstalled Chrome browser, because of the warnings in the "Reliability Monitor". Computer kept crashing, though, but I'm still with Chrome uninstalled.
2. Uninstalled the "*Intel Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Driver*" that I once got from Dell's site (*support.dell.com*, where this driver was marked with their blue `THIS PC` badge, i.e. believed to be most suitable for my PC, I guess). *See "p.s." below for more details on the driver.*
3. Following some voodoo suggestion from somewhere (I forgot where), I modified the Battery plan settings from "100%" to "98%" in two places as follows: in the computer's power options  (Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options), "Change plan settings", "Change advanced power setting". Then scroll down to "Processor power management > Maximum processor state" and change 100% to 98% for both "> On battery" and "> Plugged in".

I hope that some of this makes sense / will help!

---

p.s. More details on the driver:

```
Intel Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Driver
Version: 8.3.10209.6897, A12
Last Updated Date: 18 Mar 2020
File Name: Intel-Dynamic-Platform-and-Thermal-Framework_74P16_WIN_8.3.10209.6897_A12.EXE
File size: 14.65 MB
```

Reason for uninstalling it: I suspected that a software might cause the flukes in not recognizing the battery or deal inappropriately (shutdown) with an alleged heating etc.; also, in the "[View full driver details](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-ed/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=74p16)" for this driver, it says that it's an "*Update Package for MS Windows 32-Bit*" while mine is 64-bit (sure, they also say "*...designed to run on Microsoft Windows 64bit Operating Systems*", but I don't trust programmers).

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I made this long PowerShell one-liner using custom code. It's looking for events in the log around the time of the reboot. It downloads the code for my Get-RebootReport function and executes a few commands. It will give you an idea of what was happening around that time.

The code source is behind the URI if you want to verify it doesn't do anything other than what I claim.

```
$csvPath="$($env:temp)\temp.csv";$LogNames=@('System','Application');[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol=[enum]::GetNames([Net.SecurityProtocolType])|Foreach-Object{[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::$_};(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString( 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tonypags/PsWinAdmin/master/Public/Get-RebootReport.ps1' )| iex;$LastRebootTime = (Get-RebootReport)[0].Date;$Events=@();$LogNames|%{$FilterHashtable = @{LogName=$_;EndTime=($LastRebootTime.AddMinutes(1));StartTime=($LastRebootTime.AddMinutes(-5));};Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $FilterHashtable|%{$Events += $_}};$Events| sort TimeCreated |select LogName, TimeCreated, ProviderName, Message | export-csv $csvPath -notype; ii $csvPath
```